# Set the child ExpandableListView buttons to change the layout when clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I'm project in school and need help! I created a ExpandableListView, the problem is I can not create an onClick in the child ExpandableView buttons! I just want to change the layout when clicked on each button ... I even created the layout for each button. I've googled a lot but did not think anything more than a system when u click it tells what position the button you clicked is! I do not want it, I just want a change of layout for each button when clicked. Got that? follows my codes

```
/*
            * Preparing the list data
            */
           private void prepareListData() {
               listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
               listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

               // Adding child data
               listDataHeader.add("1°ANO");
               listDataHeader.add("2° ANO");
               listDataHeader.add("3° ANO");

               // Adding child data
               List<String> primeiro_ano = new ArrayList<String>();
               primeiro_ano.add("1M1");
               primeiro_ano.add("1M2");
               primeiro_ano.add("1M3");
               primeiro_ano.add("1M4");
               primeiro_ano.add("1M5");


               List<String> segundo_ano = new ArrayList<String>();
               segundo_ano.add("2M1");
               segundo_ano.add("2M2");
               segundo_ano.add("2M3");
               segundo_ano.add("2M4");
               segundo_ano.add("2M5");


               List<String> terceiro_ano = new ArrayList<String>();
               terceiro_ano.add("3M1");
               terceiro_ano.add("3M2");
               terceiro_ano.add("3M3");


               listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), primeiro_ano); // Header, Child data
               listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), segundo_ano);
               listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), terceiro_ano);

           }
```

}

- Sorry for bad english! I'm from Brazil.

Comment: please post your xml code that contain your Button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add,

```
expandablelistView.setOnChildClickListener()
```

here is some examples, refer following links,

[set-onclicklistener-function-on-expandablelistview-android](http://www.android-examples.com/set-onclicklistener-function-on-expandablelistview-android/)

[android-expandable-listview-simple](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)